# File Not Found exception: (file exists) - after manually deleting it

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I've stumbled upon an issue that has been puzzling me. I'm writing an app that creates mp3 files on the external storage. The thing is, if I manually go to the created directory on the phone and delete the file, whenever I try to the create the same file it throws this error:

*java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/sound1.mp3: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)*

Selecting other sounds to be created works just fine, but after I manually delete them they can't be created again due to that issue.

I've already tried deleting the file right after indicating the path and before FileOutputStream but didn't work.

Any tips?
Cheers.

Comment: Android 11 device? Can be that the used file manager (if that is what you mean with manually) did delete the file but not the entry in the MediaStore.

Comment: Precisely. Android 11, tried deleting it using a file manager to test how the app behaved, apparently there's something else to pay attention. I'll look into the documentation of MediaStore. Thanks.

Comment: @Migas11 how did you solve this?

Comment: is there any resolution ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to acknowledge the media database before trying to create another copy of the same file. So you need to call this before copying:

`sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(folder path in which your file was)));`

**Edit:** The above answer is *deprecated*! Please use the following method:

```
File file = new File(outputPath + fileName);
String filePath = file.toString();
String mimeType = "video/mp4";

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{filePath}, new String[]{mimeType}, null);
```

Example of `outputPath` and `fileName`:

```
String outputPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "My App Name") + "/";
String fileName = "break dance" + ".mp4";
```

So the `File file` should be the path of the media you want to update either because it's just deleted or it's newly added, to be visible in Gallery.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, today I learned something new.

Use case: Manually delete the file from a file manager app. Trying to recreate the file programmatically will get an FileNotFound exception: EEXIST even though the file doesn't exist, can't be created with .createNewFile(), etc. Notifying the media store worked.

Comment: Not worked for me. I don't know what to do

Comment: Check the updated method.

Comment: It did not work on Android 11

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, following user blackapps' tip. I also changed the directory, as I was using a deprecated reference. Now it is working as intended for sdk 30.